I keep getting this error when I run it on postman : "TypeError: Product.create is not a function"
I did all the connections right but when I try to test it on postman it shows this error instead.
//my models file
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {type:String, required: [true,"{PATH} is required"] , minlength : [3, "{PATH} must be 3 or more"]},
        price: {type:Number, required: [true,"{PATH} is required"], min : [0, "{PATH} must be 3 or more"]},
        description: {type:String}
    },{timestamps:true}
)



module.exports.Product = mongoose.model("Product",ProductSchema);

//my controller file
const Product = require("../models/product.model")

module.exports = {
    getAll: (req,res) => {
        Product.find()
            .then(object=> res.json(object))
            .catch(err=> res.json(err))
    },


    getOne: (req,res) => {
        Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
            .then(object=> res.json(object))
            .catch(err=> res.json(err))
    },


    create: (req,res) => {
        Product.create(req.body)
            .then(object=> res.json(object))
            .catch(err=> res.status(400).json(err))
    },


    update: (req,res) => {
        Product.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new:true, runValidators:true})
            .then(object=> res.json(object))
            .catch(err=> res.status(400).json(err))
    },

    delete: (req,res) => {
        Product.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})
            .then(confirm=> res.json(confirm))
            .catch(err=> res.json(err))
    }
}

What should I do ? even when I tried it on getAll it says "TypeError: Product.find is not a function"
please help

Remember that you're not posting here for yourself, you're posting for you and all future visitors: please [edit] your post to have a normal title that explains the core of the problem and an explanation of what you set out to do, what code you wrote to do that (including explaining why that's the code you wrote), what it did, how that differed from expectation, and what debugging and (re)searching you already did to figure things out that yielded no result. Your day being ruined is not relevant 5 years from now.

What is the name of ProductSchema module? Show the code , route and url where you have made request from postman.

Change your export to module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema); and your import to const Product = require("../models/product");
